# Numbering outside the pdf zone in latex

Tags: packages, enumerate

I use MikTeX and I use the editor TeXnicCenter. I compile my code with XeLaTeX to generate a pdf.

[image]

I wanna do like this. Could you tell me the code?

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, what have you tried so-far? Please note that this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site. Nevertheless, from your question, it is still unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lineno,lipsum}
    \newcounter{toto}
    \newcommand{\markl}{\stepcounter{toto}\marginpar{(\thetoto)}}
\begin{document}
I am trying to see if this works.\markl
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.\markl
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.
I am trying to see if this works.\markl

\end{document}
```

Please consider making a MWE next time.[image]

Comment: I do not think OP is pointing out to line-numbers. The OP here wants something else, which, only the OP can answer ;)

Comment: @Raaja You may well be right but the question is so imprecise!

Comment: thanks u!! i wanna number the lines that i choose. And the number should be outside of pdf text zone.  And the numbering symbol is (1), (2) not 1,2. help me please~~~

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: wow!! thanks a lot!!! and i use  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = gray!20] \end{mdframed} for the gray box. 1. how can i number outside of the box?   2. initialization of number is possible??  help me!! :)

Comment: @hohohaha This is a new question. Ask it if you want. In the meanwhile, you can approve my answer if this helped.